# Kernel Constraint usage in Tensorflow v1.14

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am implementing a custom dense layer with weights of dimension `12x12` in which not all the neurons from one layer are connected to another layer. So I have defined a projection matrix like below:

```py
projection_matrix = np.zeros((12, 12))
connections = [[2, 6, 9], [4, 7, 10], [0, 6, 9], [5, 8, 11], [1, 7, 10], [3, 8, 11], [0, 2, 9], [1, 4, 10],
               [3, 5, 11], [0, 2, 6], [1, 4, 7], [3, 5, 8]]
for i, connection in zip(range(projection_matrix.shape[0]), connections):
    for j in connection:
        projection_matrix[i, j] = 1
```

And then the idea is to multiply the weight matrix with this projection matrix:

```py
new_weight_matrix = np.multiply(weight_matrix, projection_matrix)  # Might as well be tf.multiply
```

I was going through the documentation of `tf.layers.dense` from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense). There is a parameter called `kernel_constraint`, whose description reads:

> An optional projection function to be applied to the bias after being updated by an Optimizer.

My question is, does passing the `projection_matrix` to this parameter (`kernel_constraint`) achieve what I intend to achieve (connect only specific neurons defined by `projection_matrix`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is: no.

This parameter applies a projection to your kernel (or bias) after the update performed by an Optimizer. It is used when you want, for example, your variable to belong to a given sub-domain. In this case, after the update performed by the optimizer, the variable is reprojected inside the feasible sub-domain.

For example, if you want your kernel to be inside `[0,1]` you can build a `kernel_constraint` like this:

```
def custom_kernel_constraint(var):
    return tf.math.maximum(tf.math.minimum(var, 1.), 0.)
```

I don't know your use case, but if you need to have only the call to `dense` do this dis-connection, then you can do a `kernel_constraint` like:

```
def disconnection_kernel_constraint(var):
    return tf.multiply(var, projection_matrix)
```

However, you must remember to initialize the kernel also by using a constant initializer multiplying a random kernel with your projection matrix, otherwise the first computation will not have the disconnection (since, the projection is only applied **after** the Optimizer update).

For example, as parameter

```
kernel_initializer= tf.constant_initializer(tf.multiply(tf.random_normal(shape=[12,12),projetion_matrix))
```

I think it is a bit more *obscure* than having the `tf.multiply` explicit in your code, but it depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have two comments: First, shouldn't the second argument to the `tf.math.maximum` function be `0.0` instead of `-1.`? Second, the only way to achieve whatever I want is by doing it manually, in the form of matrix hadamard product?

Comment: I'm updating the answer to achieve your goal with kerlnel_constraint.  Yeah, typo :)

Comment: I'll give this a try and get back, thanks for your time